# I don't understand the directions of the arrows

Tags: schematics, laptop

In theory, in the image the current comes from page 41 through cable 51 on#, but if we go to page 41 the arrow indicates that the current is coming in and not going out as indicated in the second image.

It is the part of the on/off button of an Acer aspire laptop.
Thanks so much.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I would be much more worried about the fact that none of the components actually connects to any of the wires...

Answer (score 8):

These arrows are off-sheet connectors. Their first function is to mark nets that are continued on another sheet. If there is any meaning in the direction of their symbol depends on both the schematics software and the designer of the circuit. I.e. you might use the arrow shape to indicate the direction of a signal, but this is not required and has no influence on the actual circuit.

Answer (score 4):

Those 'arrows' do not indicate the direction of the current. They are merely artistic representations of a connection going 'off page'.

They narrow down to a point to connect to the wire aesthetically. Why do they widen to the edge of the page?  You need visual help if you are tracing a net from page to page. A wide shape is easy to notice, and it's a standard shape, so you get used to that being a net continuation.